# Cast PropertyInfo to generic type

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, casting

I have the following class:

```
public class AuthContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Models.Permission> Permissions { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Models.Application> Applications { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Models.Employee> Employees { get; set; } 
    // ...
}
```

I created the extension method `Clear()` for type `DbSet<T>`. Using reflection I am able to inspect the instance of `AuthContext` and read all its properties of type `DbSet<T>` as `PropertyInfo[`]. How  can I cast the `PropertyInfo` to `DbSet<T>` in order to call the extension method on it ?

```
var currentContext = new AuthContext();
...
var dbSets = typeof(AuthContext).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
dbSets.Where(pi =>
                pi.PropertyType.IsGenericTypeDefinition &&
                pi.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(DbSet<>)).ToList()
      .ForEach(pi = ((DbSet<T>)pi.GetValue(currentContext, null)).Clear()); // !!!THIS WILL NOT WORK
```

Comment: When you say `!!!THIS WILL NOT WORK` what exactly do you mean? What happens

Comment: could you post the signature (don't need the body) of your `Clear()` method to help @Daniel Hilgarth and I clear something up :)

Comment: I wonder how `pi.PropertyType.IsGenericTypeDefinition` does not fail with you. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31771628/getting-a-dbcontext-dbsets-using-reflection?noredirect=1#comment51474495_31771628)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please see Andras Zoltan's answer for an explanation of what you are doing wrong.

However, if you use .NET 4.0, you don't need to use reflection to call the method, you can simply use the new `dynamic` keyword:

```
var currentContext = new AuthContext();
var dbSets = typeof(AuthContext).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | 
                                               BindingFlags.Instance);
dbSets.Where(pi => pi.PropertyType.IsGenericType &&
                   pi.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(DbSet<>))
      .ToList()
      .ForEach(pi => ExtensionClass.Clear((dynamic)pi.GetValue(currentContext, 
                                                               null)));
```

I changed the cast from `DbSet<T>` to `dynamic` and changed the way the method is called.
Because `Clear` is an extension method, it can't be called directly on the `dynamic` type, because `dynamic` doesn't know about extension methods. But as extension methods are not much more than static methods, you can always change a call to an extension method to a normal call to the static method.
Everything you have to do is to change `ExtensionClass` to the real class name in which `Clear` is defined.

Comment: @Daniel Hilgarth - nice; but will this work if `Clear` is an extension method? Running a quick redux of the code I get `Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: 'Tests.A<int>' does not contain a definition for 'Clear'`. It certainly would work for an instance method.  You also couldn't invoke the extension explicitly as a static either, because presumably it's `Clear<T>` and needs a generic argument.  Actually, perhaps we need the method declaration from the OP

Comment: @Andras: Ah... I missed that. Corrected.

Comment: @Daniel Hilgarth - yup; I then edited my comment (that never works does it!); this won't work if the OP's method is `Clear<T>` - which I'm guessing it must be if it works on any `DbSet<T>` (in the absence of a base class!)

Comment: @Daniel - I don't think you did actually - it's compiling and running here; now *that* is cool; I never thought dynamic dispatch extended to cracking out the correct generic parameters for a method... +100

Comment: @Andras: Yes, this works. The runtime determines, which method to call. That is most likely the same mechanism that makes it possible to pass a `dynamic` to an overloaded method where both overloads have only one parameter and still have the runtime choose the correct overload.

Comment: @Daniel Hilgarth - I tried writing mechanisms like that for some of my own projects before C#4 came along and it's a nightmare!  I'm already using dynamic in quite a few places (despite risking the wrath of Eric Lippert!); but this certainly adds an extra tool to the box - really, genuinely, awesome.

Comment: @Andras: Yeah, `dynamic` is pretty awesome. I don't like to use `dynamic` out of laziness as I don't like to use `object` out of laziness. But in case where you have to do reflection anyway, I think it is ok to use it. Whether reflection is needed in this scenario in the first place is a whole different question.

Comment: @Daniel: yeah - this one of those situations where you have to balance the need to steer the OP in the direction of solving the immediate problem as opposed to potentially bringing their world down by criticising their approach.

Comment: @Daniel @Andras: thank you guys for really express answers. I usually do not prefer using `dynamic`, but in this case I think it is acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

Your cast is wrong.

You can't cast to `(DbSet<T>)` because that's not a concrete type unless `T` is defined inside a generic method or generic type.

You have a couple of possibilities.

If DbSet has a base class (e.g. `DbSet_BaseClass` in my code below) from which you can still implement your `Clear()` method - then change it's signature from:

```
public static void Clear<T>(this DbSet<T>)
```

to:

```
public static void Clear(this DbSet_BaseClass)
```

Then you can change your cast in the `.ForEach` to `((DbSet_BaseClass)pi.GetValue...`

If you can't do that, you could reflect-invoke the `Clear` extension method by building a specific generic version of it for the `T` of the `DbSet<T>`:

```
MethodInfo myClearMethod = typeof(container_type).GetMethod(
  "Clear", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
```

Then, given a property info and context instance:

```
Type propType = pi.PropertyType;
Type typeofT = propType.GetGenericArguments[0];
MethodInfo toInvoke = myClearMethod.MakeGenericMethod(typeofT);
//now invoke it
toInvoke.Invoke(null, new[] { pi.GetValue(currentContext, null) });
```

There are lots of optimisations you can put on top of this, caching delegates etc etc, but this will work.

### Update

Or see @Daniel Hilgarth's answer for a *cool* way to dynamically dispatch the call to the extension method without having to do any of the above (dynamic dispatch effectively does something like the above, but for you with all the caching on top).  If it were me - I'd be using that.

Comment: One optimization would be to use `dynamic`. You might want to add a sample of that.

Comment: @Daniel Hilgarth - ah yes; I still think in DIY dynamic binding sometimes :)

Comment: @Daniel Hilgarth - actually, fancy putting up another solution for how you see `dynamic` working? I've had a thought about the `dynamic` case, but can't easily see a nice way to convert from `extnMethod<T>(this A<T>)` to `dynamic` that doesn't end up requiring reflection in the extension method! I'm missing something I think

Comment: Have a look at my answer. This should do it.

Comment: I was also thinking about the creating the non-generic version `public static void Clear(this DbSet set)`, but then the line `.ForEach(pi = ((DbSet)pi.GetValue(currentContext, null)).Clear());` gives me Invalid Cast Exception (cannot cast DbSet<> to DbSet). However this line is working: `DbSet testCastEmp = (DbSet) currentContext.Employees`. Am I missing something ??

Answer (score 0):

You can't cast the types because they've got no relationship to each other.  You're getting a PropertyInfo which tells you about the type, but is not the type itself.

I think you're going to want to use Type.GetMethod to locate the "Clear" method, as a MethodInfo, and then you'll be able to call MethodInfo.Invoke.

Comment: he's getting the instance from the PropertyInfo using GetValue

Comment: This is not the problem as he is not trying to cast `pi` but the result of `pi.GetValue`. (@Andras: I know you said the same thing, but I wanted to re-phrase it, because I didn't understand your comment at first... ;-))

Comment: @Daniel Hilgarth - no problem at all :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to do reflection on the DbSet to invoke the Clear Method

Try this :

```
var dbSets = typeof(AuthContext).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
            dbSets.Where(pi =>
                            pi.PropertyType.IsGenericType &&
                            pi.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(DbSet<>)).ToList()
                  .ForEach(pi =>
                      {
                          typeof(DbSet<>)
                              .MakeGenericType(pi.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0])
                              .GetMethod("Clear")
                              .Invoke(pi.GetValue(currentContext, null), null);
                      }
                      );
```

Comment: it's an extension method so he can't retrieve it off the `DbSet<>` type and `.Invoke` it