# Difference between IsGenericType and IsGenericTypeDefinition

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, system.type

What is the difference between `Type.IsGenericType` and `Type.IsGenericTypeDefinition` ? Interestingly enough, **MSDN's link for IsGenericTypeDefinition is broken**.

*Update*:
[IsGenericTypeDefinition MSDN's entry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.isgenerictypedefinition?view=net-7.0)

After playing a bit with trying to retrieve all the DbSets defined in a given DbContext, I was lead to the following, which behavior I am trying to understand: filtering properties via IsGenericType returns the desired results, while with IsGenericTypeDefinition not (does not return any).

It's interesting that from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6304702/cast-propertyinfo-to-generic-type) post I have the impression that the author did get his DbSets using IsGenericTypeDefinition, while I did not.

Follows a sample that illustrates the discussion:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    A a = new A();
    int propertyCount = a.GetType().GetProperties().Where(p => p.PropertyType.IsGenericType).Count();
    int propertyCount2 = a.GetType().GetProperties().Where(p => p.PropertyType.IsGenericTypeDefinition).Count();

    Console.WriteLine("count1: {0}  count2: {1}", propertyCount, propertyCount2);
}

// Output: count1: 1  count2: 0

public class A
{
    public string aaa { get; set; }
    public List<int> myList { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

`IsGenericType` tells you that this instance of `System.Type` represents a generic type with all its type parameters specified. For example, `List<int>` is a generic type.

`IsGenericTypeDefinition`, on the other hand, tells you that this instance of `System.Type` represents a definition from which generic types can be constructed by supplying type arguments for its type parameters. For example, `List<>` is a generic type definition.

You can get a generic type definition of a generic type by calling `GetGenericTypeDefinition`:

```
var listInt = typeof(List<int>);
var typeDef = listInt.GetGenericTypeDefinition(); // gives typeof(List<>)
```

You can make a generic type from a generic type definition by providing it with type arguments to `MakeGenericType`:

```
var listDef = typeof(List<>);
var listStr = listDef.MakeGenericType(typeof(string));
```

Comment: Don't you agree it does not make sense that [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6304702/cast-propertyinfo-to-generic-type) the author does get DbSet instances using IsGenericTypeDefinition ? Based on your answer (and some testing from my side), you will not get DbSet returned as properties when doing `GetProperties().Where(p => p.IsGenericTypeDefinition)`

Comment: @Veverke You are absolutely right, the author of the answer copy-pasted OP's code with an error. I made an edit to that answer, thank you very much!

Comment: In other words, a type for which IsGenericType returns true is a "real/complete/usable" generic type.  A type for which IsGenericTypeDefinition is true is not really usable in code yet, it is a generic type "blueprint/container".

Comment: @Veverke Yes, that's it.

Comment: Somehow related (or at least... the reason why I ended up asking this): [Getting the DbSet<>s of a DbContext](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31771628/getting-a-dbcontext-dbsets-using-reflection?noredirect=1#comment51543068_31771628)

Comment: Not interested in volunteering to [answer it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31771628/getting-the-dbcontext-dbsets-using-reflection-and-having-a-cast-to-the-proper-ge) ? :)

Comment: A good answer, but this part is incorrect (emphasis mine): "`IsGenericType` tells you that this instance of `System.Type` represents a generic type **with all its type parameters specified**" - In actuality, the `Type.IsGenericType`  property is `true` for any `Type` that refers to **any** type with generic type parameters, regardless of whether or not generic type arguments are supplied; for example the `Type` objects from `typeof(List<>)` and `typeof(Dictionary<,>)` (i.e. without specifying any type arguments) will both have `.IsGenericType == true`.

Answer (score 3):

(This answer compares all of the generic-type-related properties of `Type` in a side-by-side table below, so if you're already familiar with .NET's generics and just want a reference then just scroll down to the table)

---

First, remember the difference between *parameters* and *arguments*, especially w.r.t. *generic type parameters* and *generic type arguments* (and also *generic method type parameters* and *generic method type arguments*):

- A *generic type parameter* is the **declared** type "placeholder" in an "open" generic type.

  - For example, in `class Generic<T0,T1> {}`, the `T0` and `T1` symbols are the *generic type parameters*. Note that when simply given a generic `class` definition that's unused then there's no *type arguments*.
- A *generic type argument* is the type-identifier specified for a *generic type parameter* by a consumer of a generic class.

  - For example, in `Generic<String,Object> gen = new Generic<String,Object>` then...

    - ...the *generic type argument* for *generic type parameter `T0`* is `String`.
    - ...the *generic type argument* for *generic type parameter `T1`* is `Object`.
  - However, generic type arguments don't need to be concrete types: they can be a *generic type parameter* from the consumer's context.

    - For example, in `class Generic<TItem> { public Object Foo() { return new List<TItem>(); } }`

      - ...then (inside the `Foo` method) the `class Generic<TItem>`'s *generic type parameter `TItem`* is used as the *generic type argument* for `List<T>`'s *generic type parameter* `T`.
- Yes, if you get confused by all that don't worry because that's normal.
- Finally, *generic method type parameters* and *generic method type arguments* work the same way as *generic type parameters* and *generic type arguments*, respectively, except they're scoped to a single method:

  - For example, the class `NotGenericClass` in `class NotGenericClass { void GenericMethod<T>() {  } }` does not have any *generic type parameters*, but its method `GenericMethod<T>()` *does* have a single *generic method type parameter* - and if `GenericMethod` is never ever actually called/used/invoked then `GenericMethod` will not have any *generic method type arguments* as those only exist at *generic instantiation* sites (i.e. at the point of *generic instantiation*).

---

Given these C# classes...

```
class NormalClass { }

class Generic<T> { }

class Derived : Generic<String> { }

class HasGenericMethod { public void Foo<T>() {} }
```

...and these `Type` instances from `GetGenericArguments()`:

```
Type[] genericTypeArgs = typeof(Generic<>).GetGenericArguments();
Type genTypeArg = genericTypeArgs.Single();

Type[] genericMethodTypeArgs = typeof(HasGenericMethod).GetMethod( nameof(HasGenericMethod.Foo) ).GetGenericArguments();
Type genMethodArg = genericMethodTypeArgs.Single();
```

...then their `typeof()` expressions will have these properties:

| Example | `typeof(NormalClass)` | `typeof(Generic<>)` | `typeof(Generic<String>)` | `typeof(Derived)` | `genTypeArg` | `genMethodArg` | `typeof(Generic<String>[])` |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Type properties** |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| `Type.IsTypeDefinition` | **Yes** | **Yes** | No | **Yes** | No | No | No |
| `Type.IsGenericType` | No | **Yes** | **Yes** | No | No | No | No<sup>5</sup> |
| `Type.ContainsGenericParameters` | No | **Yes** | No | No | **Yes**<sup>4</sup> | **Yes**<sup>4</sup> | No |
| `Type.GenericTypeArguments` | Empty | Empty | `{ typeof(String) }` | Empty | Empty | Empty | Empty |
| `Type.IsConstructedGenericType` | No | No | **Yes** | No | No | No | No |
| `Type.IsGenericTypeDefinition` | No | **Yes** | No | No | No | No | No |
| **Generic parameter properties:** |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| `Type.IsGenericParameter` | No | No | No | No | **Yes** | **Yes** | No |
| `Type.IsGenericMethodParameter` | No | No | No | No | No | **Yes** | No |
| `Type.IsGenericTypeParameter` | No | No | No | No | **Yes** | No | No |
| **Methods:** |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| `Type.GetGenericArguments()` | Empty | `{ typeof(T) }` | `{ typeof(String) }` | Empty | Empty | Empty | `{ typeof(String) }` |
| `Type.GetGenericParameterConstraints()` | Exception<sup>1</sup> | Exception<sup>1</sup> | Exception<sup>1</sup> | Exception<sup>1</sup> | Empty | Empty | Exception<sup>1</sup> |
| `Type.GetGenericTypeDefinition()` | Exception<sup>2</sup> | `typeof(Generic<>)` | `typeof(Generic<>)` | Exception<sup>2</sup> | Exception<sup>2</sup> | Exception<sup>2</sup> | Exception<sup>2</sup> |

You can generate this table yourself (albiet, transposed) [using this LinqPad script](https://gist.github.com/Jehoel/44ad0b59e27f14e15061b332053c1c9e).

---

As a reminder to myself: if you have a `Type` object from `Object.GetType()` for an object that may be either a closed generic type (i.e. `Object.GetType().IsConstructedGenericType == true`), or is a non-generic type derived from that generic type, and you want to find out what, do this:

```
private static readonly Type _knownGenericType = typeof(Generic<>);

public static Boolean TryGetTypeArgsOfKnownGenericType( Object obj, [NotNullWhen(true)] out Type? actualArgType )
{
    Type t = obj.GetType();
    while( t != null )
    {
        if t.IsConstructedGenericType && t.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == _knownGenericType )
        {
            Type[] tArgs = t.GetGenericArguments();
            actualArgType = tArgs.Single();
            return true;
        }

        t = t.BaseType;
    }

    actualArgType = null;
    return false;
}
```

So this code below will print "Sucess: T := System.String" twice:

```
if( TryGetTypeArgsOfKnownGenericType( new Derived(), out Type? tArg ) )
{
    Console.WriteLine("Success: T := " + tArg.FullName);
}

if( TryGetTypeArgsOfKnownGenericType( new Generic<String>(), out Type? tArg ) )
{
    Console.WriteLine("Success: T := " + tArg.FullName);
}
```

---

Footnotes:

1. `InvalidOperationException`: "Method may only be called on a Type for which `Type.IsGenericParameter` is true."
2. `InvalidOperationException`: "This operation is only valid on generic types."
3. `typeof(T)` is `typeof(Generic<>).GetGenericArguments().Single()`
4. It's surprising that `typeof(T).ContainsGenericParameters == true` when `T` is a *generic type parameter* without an argument set (i.e. `T` is *undefined*), so I'd have expected an `InvalidOperationException` to be thrown instead.

   - [The documentation for `ContainsGenericParameters`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.containsgenericparameters?view=net-6.0) seemingly justifies returning `true` (emphasis mine):

     > For convenience and to reduce the chance of error, the `ContainsGenericParameters` property provides a standard way to distinguish between closed constructed types, which can be instantiated, and open constructed types, which cannot. **If the `ContainsGenericParameters` property returns `true`, the type cannot be instantiated.**
5. Apparently using `typeof(T[])` when `T` is a constructed generic type: the `ContainsGenericParameters` property is **false** but the `GetGenericArguments()` method returns a non-empty array of the type-arguments of `T` instead of the type-arguments of `System.Array` (which isn't actually a generic type).

   - For example:

     ```
     typeof(Generic<String>[]).IsGenericType         == false
     typeof(Generic<String>[]).GetGenericArguments() == new[] { typeof(String) }
     ```
   - This is documented in the rightmost column of the above table.
   - And described in the documentation:

     > The `ContainsGenericParameters` property searches recursively for type parameters. For example, it returns `true` for an array whose elements are type `A<T>` even though the array is not itself generic. Contrast this with the behavior of the `IsGenericType` property, which returns `false` for arrays.

---

Comment: *Because now we have support for tables in StackOverflow's Markdown:* ?

Comment: @Veverke StackOverflow added support for **real tables** in our posts at the end of 2020 ( https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/new-feature-table-support ) - so I decided to add this answer to this question that adds a table that compares the `Type` property values as that should be easier to see and compare side-by-side instead of having to read prose text or monospaced tables.

Comment: Oh now I see, great, thanks!